# How to Generate Compenent via Url

Tags: vuejs3, vuetify.js

There is a class page where If you click on a subclass it will bring you to the subclass page.  I want to have all the subclass data there and depending on the url it will render different subclasses.

My data looks like this

```
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      url: this.$route.href.split("/").pop(),

      sub1: [{ lvl: "1",desc:"sub1"},{lvl:"2", desc:"sub1"}],
      sub2: [{ lvl: "1",desc:"sub2"},{lvl:"2",desc:"sub2"}],
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

I tried to have those subclasses in an array and iterate with "if" like below. But Vue didn't allow me to use "for" and "if" at the same time.

```
<template>
  <div class="center mt-15">
    <v-card v-for="sub in sub1" :key="sub.lvl" v-if"sub.name=={{url}}">
      <v-card-text> 
           {{sub.desc}}
      </v-card-text>
    </v-card>
  </div>
</template>


<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      url: this.$route.href.split("/").pop(),

      sub1: [{ name:"sub1",lvl: "1",desc:"desc1"},{name:"sub1",lvl:"2", desc:"desc1"}],
      sub2: [{ name:"sub2",lvl: "1",desc:"desc2"},{name:"sub2",lvl:"2",desc:"desc2"}],

    };
  },
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I made my data like this

```
class[
  {name:"sub1"
   prop:[....]
  }
  {name:"sub2"
   prop[.....]
  }
]
```

Then created a computed data that iterate through class to match url and sub name

```
subClass: function () {
  for (let index = 0; index < this.class.length; index++) {
    if (this.class[index].name == this.url) {
      return this.class[index];
    }
  }
  return "nothing";
},
```

And lastly, this is how my component looks

```
<v-card v-for="sub in subClass.prop" :key="sub.lvl" class="">
  <v-card-title>Level {{ sub.lvl }}</v-card-title>
  <v-card-text >
    <h3>{{ sub.title }}</h3>
    <p class="pre-formatted">{{ sub.desc }} </p>
  </v-card-text>
</v-card>
```